# Problem with color picker (brush tool) in Photoshop 8

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have created a rectangle and on that rectangle I masked it. Now I wanted to pick up color with brush tool pressing `Alt+Click` but it is not picking the exact color. It only picks up black or white color. It seems staying at masked layer it picks up only black and white color.

Comment: If I rasterize  the rectangle, then it picks up the color what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You must have the mask layer selected.

In your layers panel, make sure you have your content layer selected instead:

[image]

Comment: Yes! I did that but no luck. If I masked to image and pickup the color then it is picking up the color staying at content layer but not with created rectangle layer.

Comment: What version of Photoshop are you using? I just tried it and it picks the color of the content PLUS the mask (so if the content is red and the mask goes to 0 to 100% alpha, and I click in the middle, it gives me pink).

Comment: .....photoshop 8.0